# How to insert some data value inplace of all field of table with sequalizer in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am a beginner in nodejs. I want to save record in table but i want to save some fields in place of all fields in mysql, becoz i  have existing database schema and make an API using sequalizer & nodejs.

Comment: What so you mean by "save some fields in place of all fields in mysql"? Is it an insert or an update query?

Comment: @Wing-OnYuen, thanks for reply. It is an insert query

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work?

Comment: @Wing-OnYuen, thanks for reply. Wing-On Yuen, I have done it to ommit the attribute in model.

Comment: Have you tried to use [sequelize raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html)?

Comment: @Wing-OnYuen, I have resolve my problem by using sequalize model. Tahnks :)